# Probability of maximum bigger than another maximum

Tags: probability

Given $n$ i.i.d. random variables $X_1, \ldots X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_1^2)$ and  $n(n-1)/2$ i.i.d. random variables $Y_1, \ldots Y_{n(n-1)/2} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_2^2)$ and independent w.r.t to the first set of random variables, I'm interested in the probability of the event

\begin{equation}
Z_0 := \max\{Y_1,\ldots,Y_{n(n-1)/2}\}> Z_1 :=\max\{X1,\ldots,X_n\} 
\end{equation}

In particular I would like to have an asymptotic upper bound in terms of $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ for the probability of the event. Simple computer simulations suggest that the probability goes to zero for large $n$ in the case where $\sigma_1^2 =2, \sigma_2^2=1$.

**Attempt**: I know that we can write the event as

\begin{equation}
\bigcup \limits_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \{ Z_0 > t \} \cap \{Z_1 = t\} 
\end{equation}
and I also know that the cdfs for $Z_0$ and $Z_1$ are given by $\Phi(x/\sigma_2)^{n(n-1)/2}$ and $\Phi(x/\sigma_1)^{n}$ but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be very appreciated.

**EDIT (ANSWER)**: The question got asked again and answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347194/probability-of-achieving-the-maximum-among-absolute-value-of-gaussians), after I deleted it and posted it on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is equivalent to the following:

- let $X_1$ be a random variable with c.d.f. $F_{X_1}(x)$ and p.d.f. $f_{X_1}(x)$.
- let $X_2$ be a random variable with c.d.f. $F_{X_2}(x)$ and p.d.f. $f_{X_2}(x)$.

What is the probability $P(X_1 < X_2)$?

The answer is

$$
P(X_1 < X_2) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}P(X_1 < x)f_{X_2}(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(x)dx.
$$

Comment: As stated in my question I would need an asymptotic upper bound, could you elaborate on that?